# build a online map js api like google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javascript

We want to build a js map api like to display the map in the web page just like the google map.

But we can not use the google api,so we want to build it ourself.

Of course we can not and do not need to make the api as power as google map's.

We just need the basice map display/move/zoom,and change map type ,add control,draw overlay,show infomation window .

So I wonder if there are any open soure related js lib we can use?

BTW, the map we will provide has been splitted as tiles like google. So It would be better if the js lib can support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/).

Comment: It seems that the oepnlayers is under heavy development,any other choice?

Comment: They are under development, but you can use latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the map as an image and use a jquery plugin like this

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/pan-zoom/

Answer (score 0):

Besides Openlayers, **[jQuery Geo](http://jquerygeo.com/)** is also an option for some small projects.